# How do I implement an access of register if it has the multiple access options in UVM IP-XACT?

Tags: uvm

I'm trying to understand the [IP-XACT User Guide](https://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/ip-xact/IP-XACT_User_Guide_2018-02-16.pdf) schema for making the RAL model.
Especially, if I have a register called `DEV_STAT` as below, I understood that `DEV_STAT` contains the `DEV_ID` and `REV_ID` bit fields.

Q1)
What if `DEV_ID` is RO (Read_Only) but `REV_ID` has a RW (Read_Write) access?  How do I implement `DEV_STAT`'s `spirit:access`?

```
        <spirit:register>
            <spirit:name>DEV_STAT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:addressOffset>0x0</spirit:addressOffset>
            <spirit:size>8</spirit:size>
            <spirit:access> **read-only or read-write ?**</spirit:access>
            <spirit:reset>
                <spirit:value>0x0</spirit:value>
                <spirit:mask>0xFF</spirit:mask>
            </spirit:reset>
            <spirit:field>
                <spirit:name>DEV_ID</spirit:name>
                <spirit:bitOffset>3</spirit:bitOffset>
                <spirit:bitWidth>5</spirit:bitWidth>
                <spirit:access>read-only</spirit:access>
            </spirit:field>
            <spirit:field>
                <spirit:name>REV_ID</spirit:name>
                <spirit:bitOffset>0</spirit:bitOffset>
                <spirit:bitWidth>3</spirit:bitWidth>
                <spirit:access>read-write</spirit:access>
            </spirit:field>
```

Q2)
I came across the usage of parameter as below, But I couldn't get detail information for the usage of `parameter` and its name and value. I think this probably optional but don't know what is the purpose and usage.

```
         <spirit:parameters>
                <spirit:parameter>
                    <spirit:name>Reserved</spirit:name>
                    <spirit:value>true</spirit:value>
                </spirit:parameter>
            </spirit:parameters>


      <spirit:register>
            <spirit:name>TOPINT</spirit:name>
            <spirit:addressOffset>0x1</spirit:addressOffset>
            <spirit:size>8</spirit:size>
            <spirit:access>read-only</spirit:access>
            <spirit:reset>
                <spirit:value>0x0</spirit:value>
                <spirit:mask>0x1F</spirit:mask>
            </spirit:reset>
            <spirit:field>
                <spirit:name>reserved</spirit:name>
                <spirit:displayName>RESERVED</spirit:displayName>
                <spirit:bitOffset>5</spirit:bitOffset>
                <spirit:bitWidth>3</spirit:bitWidth>
                <spirit:access>read-only</spirit:access>
                <spirit:parameters>
                    <spirit:parameter>
                        <spirit:name>Reserved</spirit:name>
                        <spirit:value>true</spirit:value>
                    </spirit:parameter>
                </spirit:parameters>
            </spirit:field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 3.1.5 *Component Memory Maps and Registers* shows an example XML file for an I2C design.  It does not have a `<spirit:access>` element for the register, only for the bit fields.  Like your design, the fields each have different access modes.  You should be able to omit the `<spirit:access>` element for your register.

The usage of parameters is optional.  Section 3.2.3 *Parameter Passing* indicates that parameter values can be overridden by top-level designs.  This is similar in principle to Verilog modules that use parameters.  When you instantiate the module, you have the option of assigning a different parameter value at instantiation.